# Is $f_k(x) := k \sin \left(\frac1x\right) x^{k-1} - \cos\left(\frac1x\right) x^{k-2}$ continuous at zero?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

I'm trying to improve my proof writing due to exams. Is my reasoning even correct in the first place and understandable? If not what could be improved?

---

> Let $f_k$ be a set of functions from the real numbers to the real numbers, where $$f_k(x) := k \sin \left(\frac1x\right) x^{k-1} - \cos\left(\frac1x\right) x^{k-2}$$ except for $x=0$, then $f_k(0)=0$ and k is an integer. For which $k$ is this function continuous in zero?

---

We are going to make case distinction for different $k$s and we are going to use the limit characterization in order to show continuity. We claim for $k\geq 3$ the function $f_k$ is continuous and for $k < 3$ the function is not continuous.

Let $k\geq 3$. We find, where $i,j$ are some natural numbers $i,j,l>0$, that $f_k(x)=i \sin(1/x)x^{j}-cos(1/x)x^{l}$. In order to show $\lim_{x_n \rightarrow 0} f_{k}(x_n)=f(0)=0$, where $x_n$ is a sequence in the real numbers, note that $sin,cos$ can be maximally $1,-1$. Thus we find $-ix_n^{j}-x_n^{l} \leq f_{k}(x) \leq ix_n^{j}+x_n^{l}$. But by the squeeze theorem we find and because the functions on the left and right side are continuous, meaning we can simply substitute the limit of $x_n$, we find indeed $\lim_{x_k \rightarrow 0} f(x_k)=f(0)=0$. Thus for $k\geq 3$ the function is continous.

It remains to show that the functoin does not converge for values two and smaller.

Let $k=2$. In order to show that the function is not continuous it is sufficient to construct a sequence such that $\lim_{x_n \rightarrow 0} f(x_n) \neq f(0)=0$ We notice that $f_2(x)=2 \sin(1/x) x -\cos(1/x)$. Choose $x_n=1/(2 \pi n)$. We find $f_2(x_n)=2 \sin(2 \pi n )(2 \pi n )-\cos(2 \pi n)=-1$. This is not equals to zero and it follow that the function is for $k=2$ not continuous in $x=0$

Further assume $k=1$ and with the same reasoning, just with a slightly different series $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$. Again with substituting $k=1$ we find $f_1(x)=\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)/x$. $f_1(\frac{1}{2\pi n})=- 2 \pi n \cos(2 \pi n) = -2 \pi n$. This doesnt even converge and it follows not continuous.

Assume now $k\leq 0$. By looking at the series $x_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi n}$. We find with substitution $f_{k}(x)=k \sin(1/x)/x^{i}-|cos(1/x)/x^{j}$ where $i,j>0$.  We have $f_{k}(1/(2 \pi n))=k \sin (2 \pi n )/(1/(2 \pi n))^{i}-\cos(2 \pi n)/(1/(2 \pi n))^{j}=-(2\pi n)^{j} $ but this also doesn't even converge. qed.

Comment: Why introducing $i,j,l$ ?

Comment: I see I attempted to make things easier because the exact values are irrelevant but I think I made it more complicated

Comment: I also think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say some positive things, offer some criticisms, and then suggest an alternative approach.

**The positive:** The idea of breaking the proof down into separate cases (depending on $k$) is good.  In the $k \geq 3$ case, the idea of using that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are bounded between $-1$ and $1$, together with the squeeze theorem, is also good.

**Some criticisms.** I'll stick to the $k \geq 3$ case:

- The introduction of $i, j, l$ is unnecessary.  We'll come back to this later.
- You write $\lim_{x_n \to 0} f_k(x_n) = f_k(0)$.  While the reader will probably get what you mean, it would be more accurate to write $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_k(x_n) = f_k(0)$.
- You write "Thus, we find $-ix_n^i - x_n^l \leq f_k(x) \leq ix_n^j + x_n^l$."  Here, you presumably meant $f_k(x_n)$ rather than $f_k(x)$.  Also, it would definitely be good to show exactly how you obtained these inequalities.
- You then write

> by the squeeze theorem we find and because the functions on the left
> and right side are continuous, meaning we can simply substitute the
> limit of $x_n$, we find indeed $\lim_{x_n \to 0} f(x_k) = f(0) = 0$."

This sentence is very unclear.  The central issue is: What exactly are the "functions" on the left and right sides?  The left and right sides of your inequality are sequences $-ix_n^i - x_n^l$ and $ix_n^j + x_n^l$, which aren't themselves functions of $x$.  I think what you mean to say is something like:

> Consider the functions $g(x) = -ix^i - x^l$ and $h(x) = ix^j + x^l$.  We have shown that $g(x_n) \leq f_k(x_n) \leq h(x_n)$.  Moreover, since $g$ and $h$ are continuous (because $i,j,l$ ... I guess we're assuming they're positive?), it follows that $g(x_n) \to g(0) = 0$ and $h(x_n) \to h(0) = 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Therefore, by the squeeze theorem, ...

Notice that even this rephrasing doesn't completely fix the problem, because the relationship between $i,j,l$ and $k$ wasn't ever made clear.  (Of course, that'll be resolved once the proof is rewritten without $i,j,l$.)  In particular:

- It's not clear where you used the assumption that $k \geq 3$.

**An alternative approach.** For the case $k \geq 3$, you don't need to use sequences.  Instead, using the triangle inequality $|x - y| \leq |x| + |y|$,
one can observe that
\begin{align*}
|f_k(x)| & = \left|k \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) x^{k-1} - \cos\left( \frac{1}{x}\right) x^{k-2} \right| \\
& \leq k \left| \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right| |x|^{k-1} + \left| \cos\left( \frac{1}{x}\right) \right| |x|^{k-2}
\end{align*}
I'll leave the rest of the argument to you, which involves the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Ok this is a very detalied criticism. Thank you for you're effort. It's going to take some time to process it.

Comment: So basically the main point is I should not introduce things or generally do things unecessarly and I should not do things in my head, rather I should explain what I do carefully

Comment: The main point is that a proof should be logically clear and complete.  So, for example, if your proof involves an assumption (like $k \geq 3$), then it should be clear where you use that assumption.  Similarly, if you need to define a function (like $g(x)$) or variables (like $i,j,l$), then that's fine, but you need to state clearly what those functions or variables are.  Finally, one should distinguish between different objects (example: the function $f(x) = x^2$ is not quite the same thing as the sequence $x_n = n^2$).

Comment: ok thank you very much